# Is it possible to push a page from down to up?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to migrate one iphone app to wp7.
Is it possible to push a page from down to up in wp7?

Comment: erm .. have no idea what you mean. Can you describe what "pushing a page from down to up" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for page transitions like the 'sheet up' animation seen on iPhone.

Check out http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-transitions-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api - the code there uses the [silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), and references `TurnstileTransition`, but you can do the same with one of the other transtions. The one you are looking for is `SlideTransition`.