# How to create a slide screen in wp7? (like android slide-down screen)

Tags: windows-phone-7, screen, slide

How to create a slide screen (left to right, right to left, botton to up, up to botton) like we have the slide-down screen in android, for exemple?

I need to do this in two ways:
1. touch in a element, like a button and the screen slides to.
2. drag a little bit like we have in android, and the screen slides to.

There is a toolkit, or component in wp7 to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about page transitions - this can be acheived using the Silverlight Toolkit. See my answer here.

[Is it possible to push a page from down to up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975756/is-it-possible-to-push-a-page-from-down-to-up/8976309#8976309)

If you're talking about something else, please be more specific - a sample app / place to see this functionality on Android would be useful.